# Galois invariant rational functions and base change

Tags: galois-cohomology, rational-functions

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety defined over a perfect field $k$, let $\bar k$ be
the algebraic closure of $k$, let $X_{\bar k}$ be the base change of $X$ over $\bar k$ and let $G ={\rm Gal}(\bar k/k)$ be the absolute Galois group. Is it true that the equality $$k(X) = \bar k(X_{\bar k})^G$$ holds. That is any $G$-invariant rational function is a rational function defined over $k$?

Comment: Yes. See p7 and exercise 1.12 of "Silverman - The arithmetic of elliptic curves".